# Is it possible to update existing Dynamo DB table from Terraform

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I am trying to create a terraform module with the help of which I can make an entry to existing Dynamo DB table.
I have got this code which create dynamo DB table

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "basic-dynamodb-table" {
  name           = "GameScores"
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity  = 20
  write_capacity = 20
  hash_key       = "UserId"
  range_key      = "GameTitle"

  attribute {
    name = "UserId"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "GameTitle"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "TopScore"
    type = "N"
  }

  ttl {
    attribute_name = "TimeToExist"
    enabled        = false
  }

  global_secondary_index {
    name               = "GameTitleIndex"
    hash_key           = "GameTitle"
    range_key          = "TopScore"
    write_capacity     = 10
    read_capacity      = 10
    projection_type    = "INCLUDE"
    non_key_attributes = ["UserId"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "dynamodb-table-1"
    Environment = "production"
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can make changes in existing dynamo db table.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you exactly mean with 'make changes'? You can change anything besides the partition & range key without terraform destroying and recreating the table. If you want to import an existing table into terraform there is `terraform import` (https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html)

Comment: thanks mate for your warm welcome, 
coming to the question, I don't want to create or re-create any thing, I just want to add entry in dynamo db table with the help of terraform.

Answer (score 4):

For adding entries to a table you can take a look at the [aws_dynamodb_table_item](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table_item.html) resource. Here is an example that you can use to add an entry to your table:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "item1" {
    table_name     = aws_dynamodb_table.basic-dynamodb-table.name
    hash_key       = aws_dynamodb_table.basic-dynamodb-table.hash_key
    range_key      = aws_dynamodb_table.basic-dynamodb-table.range_key

    item = <<ITEM
{
    "UserId": {"S": "user"},
    "GameTitle": {"S": "gamex"},
    "TopScore": {"N": "42"}
}
ITEM
}
```

Comment: it seems like it was gonna work but at the end it gave me this error:

aws_dynamodb_table_item.Tagging: Creating...


Error: ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed


  on rider.tf line 1, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "Tagging":
   1: resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "Tagging" {

Comment: I’m having trouble analysing the error message and it seems like your Terraform config has changed. As this is not related to the original post, I kindly ask you to open a new question for this and include your current Terraform file as well as the complete error message.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, as I first imported the configuration of existing dynamo db table and then tried to add one item to it. I did not change anything else.